# Import excel sheet with Powershell script, turn columns into variables to create emails for users with access to shared mailboxes

Tags: powershell, office365, azure-powershell

I've created the following script to create an email for users as well as adding said users to a specific shared mailbox depending on what department they are a part of. So far this script creates the user successfully but doesn't add them to the desired shared mailbox. Is there a way to do this in one script or do I have to stick with having separate scripts. One to create an email for the user and one to put that user in the shared mailbox?

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\AddingUser.csv" | foreach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -PhoneNumber $_.PhoneNumber -Department $_.Department -Title $_.Title -UsageLocation $_.UsageLocation -Password $_.Password | set-msoluserlicense -AddLicenses STANDARDPACK}

$Person = $_.DisplayName
$Dept = $_.Department

if ( $Dept -eq 'Scheduling' )
{
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Scheduling" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $Person;
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Renewals" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $Person;
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Scans" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $Person;
}
elseif ( $Dept -eq 'Customer Care')
{
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Renewals" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $Person;
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "AP CustomerService" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $Person;
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Scans" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $Person;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to use correct code formatting (4 spaces).

Comment: Move the `}` from the end of the first line to after the last `}` in the script.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician gahhhhhh can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the user is not added to a shared mailbox is that you are using the `$_` variable incorrectly.

The `$_` variable can only be used in conjunction with pipeline output. In this case when you are assigning `$Person` and `$Dept` their values are set to null since `$_.DisplayName` and `$_.Department` do not exist outside of the ForEach-Object block above. Since `$Person` and `$Dept` are null your if blocks will never run.

I've updated the script to how I'd accomplish the task in your shoes.

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\AddingUser.csv"

foreach($user in $users)
{
    # Splat the params for easier reading
    $msol_params = @{
        DisplayName = $user.DisplayName
        FirstName = $user.FirstName
        LastName = $user.LastName
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        PhoneNumber = $user.PhoneNumber
        Department = $user.Department
        Title = $user.Title
        UsageLocation = $user.UsageLocation
        Password = $user.Password
    }

    New-MsolUser @msol_params | Set-MsolUserLicense -AddLicenses STANDARDPACK

    # switch instead of ifelse to simplify adding new departments
    switch($user.Department)
    {
        'Scheduling' {
            Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Scheduling" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $user.DisplayName
            Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Renewals" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $user.DisplayName
            Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Scans" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $user.DisplayName
        }
        'Customer Care' {
            Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Renewals" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $user.DisplayName
            Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "AP CustomerService" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $user.DisplayName
            Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Scans" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All –User $user.DisplayName
        }
        Default {
            Write-Error -Message "Invalid Department for user: $($user.DisplayName)"
        }
    }
}
```